# Setting Direct Reports in Azure Active Directory ( WAAD )

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Does anyone know how I go about setting the Direct Reports of a Windows Azure Active Directory ( WAAD ) from the Azure Management Console.

I can create the accounts easily enough but there doesn't appear to be any tools to set anything other than very basic details.

Ideally I'd like to set the direct reports and manager, office and other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a quick tool available to do this. However, if you don't mind writing some code, you could spin up a comsole app that updates these properties using the Azure AD Graph API.

- Update user's properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151671.aspx
- Update user's manager: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151673.aspx

A sample .Net console app using Azure AD Graph API is here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet

Hope this helps.